# Keep track of objects updates in vue.js

Tags: rest, vue.js

I have an array of objects in vue.js. Each object is a model. I'd like keep track of every updated object (not just the updated values) so I can have a big "save" button to push updated data to the server.

The goal is to push only the updated models. If I have 1000 rows in my array I don't want to push 1000 updates to the server (database) but only the ones I have edited.

Thanks

Update with some code

```
<ul>
    <li v-for="item in items" :key="item.id">
        <input v-model="item.title" />
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Just add an extra boolean property `edited: true` to every object after editing it, then filter out the array to see which objeects have `edited:true` and push the filtered array to server

Comment: Ok but how do I know which object has been edited ? How do I flag my object ?

Comment: how are you editing the oject

Comment: I updated the question with sample code.

Comment: Hm. Create empty array named changedItems. Register callback for onchange event for input like this @change="update(item.id)". Update callback will do something like this function update(id) { this.changedItems.push(id) }. And Save button will trigger method, which will cycle through changedItems array and call sql update only for particular, changed rows.

Answer (score 0):

Add an `editedTitle: ''` property to you object and set it as `v-model`.

now add a onblur event listener to the input and push the item to another array if inputs title is edited

```
<ul>
    <li v-for="item in items" :key="item.id">
        <input v-model="item.editedTitle" @blur="addToUpdated(item)/>
    </li>
</ul>

data(){
    return {
        items;[],
        updatedItems:[]
    }
}
methods:{
    addToUpdated(item){
        if(item.title !== item.editedTitle){
            this.updatedItems.push(item);
        }
    }
}
```